# Error including GLFW files

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile, glfw, mingw32

I am trying to create a project using GLFW3 while compiling on mingw for windows and I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\jgelderl\Documents\Test>mingw32-make
g++ -c  Main.cpp
Main.cpp:6:24: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

Here is the makefile that I am using:

```
CC = g++
OUT_EXE = Main.exe
OUT_EXE_TEST = Test.exe
LINK_FLAGS = -L"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib" -lWinMM -L"C:\glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN32\lib-mingw" -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32
INC_ DIRS = -I"C:\glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN32\include"
CFLAGS = -c 

all: Main.exe

Main.exe: Main.o game.o Block.o Board.o
        $(CC) -o Main.exe $(INC_DIRS) Main.o game.o Block.o Board.o $(LINK_FLAGS)

test: Test.exe

Test.exe: Test.o game.o Block.o Board.o
        $(CC) -o Test.exe Test.o game.o Block.o Board.o $(LINK_FLAGS)

Main.o: Main.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Main.cpp

game.o: game.cpp game.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) game.cpp

Block.o: Block.cpp Block.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Block.cpp

Board.o: Board.cpp Board.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Board.cpp

Test.o: Test.cpp greatest.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Test.cpp

clean:
        rm Main.exe Test.exe *.o

rebuild: clean all
```

I am not super experienced with makefiles but I am trying to use it to learn more about the build process. I have also put the GLFW library and include files in the mingw directories but that has not helped either. Am I doing something wrong in my makefile or do I maybe have something else set up incorrectly?

Comment: That's not an error from make. That's an error from `g++` telling you it can't find a header file with that name (under any of the locations it searches by default and under any you added with `-I`). Where does that file actually live?

Comment: @EtanReisner glfw3.h is in C:\glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN32\include\GLFW which is what I am using in my -I command

Comment: Notice the compilation command being run? `g++ -c  Main.cpp` Your `-I` flag isn't being used there. You need `-I` flags for compilation and `-L` flags for linking.

Comment: So I added my includes to the CFLAGS and it works now. I know I tried that before but I must have had something else wrong then too. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the include directory was not being used to build each object.

Original:

```
CFLAGS = -c
```

New:

```
CFLAGS = -c $(INC_DIRS)
```

This change fixed the problem.